# Is there any algorithm for finding LINES by PIXEL COLORS on picture?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors, line, straight-line-detection

So I have Image like this

[image: CG generated bathroom]
<sub>(source: [de-viz.ru](http://www.de-viz.ru/catalog/new2/Holm/hvannaya.jpg))</sub>

I want to get something like this (I hevent drawn all lines I want but I hope you can get my idea)

[image: Black & White CG generated bathroom with some red lines between tiles]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/lines.jpg))</sub>

I need algorithm for finding all straight lines on it by just reading colors of pixels. No hard math, no Haar, no Hough. Some algorithm which would be based on points colors. I want to give to algorithm parameters like min line length and max line distortion. I want to get relative to picture pixel coords start and end points of lines.

So I need algorithm for finding straight lines of different colors on picture. Algorithm which would be based on idea of image of different colors and Lines of static colors. Yes - such algorithm will not work for images with lots of shadows and lights. But It willl probably be fast (I hope so).

Is there any such algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599326/how-to-use-haar-wavelet-to-detect-lines-on-an-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596722/is-there-any-super-fast-algorithm-for-finding-lines-on-picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IPOL : LSD: a Line Segment Detector](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/)

[image]

Comment: on their server Computation took 0.54s... Hm... I have 30 fps 2k video... Going to try this one soon=)

Comment: There should be a lot of research in this area for computer vision applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an edge detect filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just do some post-processing. You get *all* edges from LSD, then you only keep the ones you want by computing their length.