# algorithms to detect lines in an image?

Tags: algorithm, straight-line-detection

Are there any (easy, quick, best) algorithms to detect lines from an image file?

Ideally, the image will be converted to a 2-dimensional array with 0's and 1's where 1 denotes the dots so the task is to use as few lines as possible that cover the dots.

Comment: There is so much information missing, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Have a look at this StackOverflow question: [Is there any super fast algorithm for finding LINES on picture?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596722/1364007).

Comment: I think the first sentence will give you responses you don't intend.  (Like the last comment?)  I would expand the second paragraph and change the title.  I don't think you're looking for lines in the same sense that "everyone else" is looking for lines.

Comment: The [hough transform](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) will give you the paramrters for lines in an image. From there you could draw the lines yourself.

Comment: Just a link that I came across today. It may be helpful: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/?utm_content=buffer4eb7f&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Algorithms that do that exist. You need to use kernel or mask on an image in order to transform it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29

Many libraries have that built in, for example openCV.